# How to improve lossy compression of NVENC HEVC with FFmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg, nvidia-graphics-card, h.265

There are a lot of answers about `h264_nvenc` settings. But I didn't find code examples for tuning NVENC HEVC lossy encoding settings on latest GPU, for example on `Tesla T4`.

These are my current setings. It seems to me that some of these commands do not do anything. Useful for `h.264` `-b_ref_mode:v middle` doesn't work with `hevc`. Is there anything I can do to make it better?

```
command += [
    '-vcodec', 'hevc_nvenc',
    '-pix_fmt', 'yuv420p', '-preset', 'slow',
    '-b:v', '4M', '-maxrate:v', '5M', '-bufsize:v', '8M',
    '-profile', 'rext', '-rc', 'vbr_hq',
    '-temporal-aq', '1',
    '-rc-lookahead', '32', '-refs:v', '16', '-bf', '3',
    '-coder:v', '1', '-vsync', '0',
    '-use_editlist', '0', '-movflags', '+faststart'
]
```

Answer (score 0):

-pix_fmt p010le
-preset slow
-profile main10
-level 6.2
-tier high
-rc vbr_hq
-rc-lookahead 32
-spatial_aq 1
-temporal_aq 1
-nonref_p 1
-init_qpP 1
-init_qpB 1
-init_qpI 1
-weighted_pred  1

Answer (score 0):

As indicated [here](https://gist.github.com/nico-lab/e1ba48c33bf2c7e1d9ffdd9c1b8d0493) you would need to set -b_ref_mode 2. It's looking for a integer and you're feeding it a string.

Comment: It is not looking for an integer. Anyway, it in not usable without this commit. https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/7303

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunatelly -b_ref_mode middle and -b_ref_mode each were broken for a long time. First because of https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/7303 and second because of https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/7301.

And then globally because of https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/9130.